# Invalid entries in edit changelog

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21631405/revisions) shows changes I did not make, attributed to my suggested edit. I did not change contents of database examples (Qty columns). Similarly, I did not add "(with how many times it occured)". Same thing happened while editing [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/417279/revisions) (revision 2). See [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417262/how-can-i-install-open-office/417279#comment537827_417279).

That is a bit problematic, as it now attributes those changes to me.

Did I do something wrong, is that a bug in stack exchange, or should it work that way?

Comment: If you're telling the truth, it's certainly a bug. A monumentally weird bug.

Comment: That is an edit clash most likely. Let me find the dupe

Comment: What likely happened here is that the OP edited during the 5 minute grace period before you submitted your edit. In that case, the system attempts to merge the edits.

Comment: @bart this has come from an edit in the Edit Review queue. I don't think it is duplicate of that, though there are others which at least touch on the problem.

Comment: Another example, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219834/using-a-meta-post-to-abuse-the-editing-feature#comment711667_219834

Comment: Your first example (your suggested edit to "SQL : return all rows that contain particular value more than once") is very likely a duplicate and related to the grace period as the OP probably edited within the grace period to change those value after you started your edit so you were working off of a different version of "Revision 1".

Comment: However, your 2nd example is a bit odd.  You [rejected the suggested edit](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/219530) and then what happened?  It looks like you submitted a 2nd edit about 15 seconds after you rejected the edit.  Do you remember how you initiated the edit?

Comment: @psubsee2003 OK, I'll remove that comment. Thanks.